# How best to stop Link component from redirecting when a delete icon is clicked

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a reusable card component that allows me to render profile details in a gallery component. Clicking on any of the card redirects to the person's profile details using `Link` from `react-router-dom`. Now, I want to add delete icon on each card to allow the viewer to delete any of the profiles.

Understandably, clicking anything in the card redirects. Is there any way to avoid redirecting but just deleting the profile when the `delete` icon is clicked or any other workaround for this use case.

Here's the code snippet

```
const Card = ({ member, addTrash=false, removeFavorite }) => (
  <Link to={`/profiles/${member.user_id}`} className="member__card">
    <div className={`member__card__body ${className}`}>

     <img src={member.photo} alt={member.user_name} />
     {addTrash ? <span className="member__card__delete" onClick=
     {removeFavorite}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></span> : null}
   </div>
   <div className="member__card__footer">
    <h3>{member.user_name}</h3>
    <p>{member.age} &bull; {member.location}</p>
   </div>
 </Link>
);
```

Help is most appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: The onClick event may be bubbling up to the surrounding Link component. Try adding `e.stopPropagation()` to your event handler.

Comment: The whole card is wrapped in the Link so clicking anywhere on the card will follow the link. You need to provide a way to allow the user to click on the trash icon so it can call the removeFavorite function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out that `e.stopPropagation()` didn't serve this use case. The fix was to call `preventDefault()` in the `removeFavorite` function.

```
removeFavorite = (id, e) => {
  e.preventDefault() // This did the fix
  this.props.deleteFavorite(id) // Delete the item
}
```

And for the Card component at the site of call

```
-------------
-------------
<Card member={{}} addTrash={true} removeFavorite={this.removeFavorite.bind(null, member.id}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is by moving the icon to somewhere outside the react-router Link.
Eg.

```
const Card = ({ member, addTrash=false, removeFavorite }) => (
  <div>
    <Link to={`/profiles/${member.user_id}`} className="member__card">
      <div className={`member__card__body ${className}`}>
        <img src={member.photo} alt={member.user_name} />
      </div>
      <div className="member__card__footer">
        <h3>{member.user_name}</h3>
        <p>{member.age} &bull; {member.location}</p>
      </div>
    </Link>
    {addTrash ? <span className="member__card__delete" onClick=
    {removeFavorite}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></span> : null}
  </div>
);
```

Also, being that you have a class `member__card__body ${className}` that wraps the card body, another way is by making only the image clickable, that is, enclosing the image with Link. That way the user can click on other parts of the card without being redirected.
Eg.

```
const Card = ({ member, addTrash=false, removeFavorite }) => (
  <div>
    <div className={`member__card__body ${className}`}>
      <Link to={`/profiles/${member.user_id}`} className="member__card">
        <img src={member.photo} alt={member.user_name} />
      </Link>
        {addTrash ? <span className="member__card__delete" onClick=
        {removeFavorite}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></span> : null}
    </div>
    <div className="member__card__footer">
      <h3>{member.user_name}</h3>
      <p>{member.age} &bull; {member.location}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
);
```

I hope this helps?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @T Porter in the comments, your span code should be

```
{addTrash ? <span className="member__card__delete" onClick=
     {(e)=>{removeFavorite();e.stopPropagation();}><i className="fa fa-trash"></i></span> : null}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another thing I think you can do is to use css. You can add a class or an id to the `delete` button and give it a position of absolute and increase the z-index to make it sit right on top.